# How can I write a Swedish letter using i3wm as a window manager on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, i3-window-manager

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and as a window manager i3wm. I have a German keyboard, how can I write the Swedish letter "å" (basically any foreign letter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it finally with `xmodmap`
You can remap keys with a command like this:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  38 = a A a A aring Aring ae"
```

This remaps `right alt` and `right alt + shift` to å and Å.
The keycodes can vary, so you have to check for the right keycode with `xmodmap -pke`.
In order to keep those changes also after a restart you can add the command to your .bashrc or .zshrc or whatever you use.